# Polynomial equation with complex numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

I'm studying linear algebra and there are a few problems from the book in the section on complex numbers I'm having trouble with. I've solved most of the questions in this chapter - I need a little help with these last five. Here's one of them - there are two statements and I have to answer true or false for each one.

1. If $z_0$ is a solution for the equation $z^{13}-13z^7+7z^3-3z+1=0$ then $\overline{z}_0$ is also a solution for it.
2. if $z_0$ is a solution for the equation $z^2+iz+2=0$ then $\overline{z}_0$ is also a solution for it.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Look up the Conjugate Root Theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 is true, by taking the conjugate of both sides of the equation, and then apply properties of conjugates.

2 is false, since the coefficient of the z term is not real, it can be shown to be false by a similar method as in 1.

Comment: Yep - makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For 1 just apply conjugation.

For 2, one has to argue differently: suppose $z_0$ and $\overline{z_0}$ are both solutions; then
$$
\begin{cases}
z_0^2+iz_0+2=0\\
\overline{z_0}^2+i\overline{z_0}+2=0
\end{cases}
$$
Subtract the two equations, getting
$$
(z_0-\overline{z_0})(z_0+\overline{z_0})+i(z_0-\overline{z_0})=0
$$
which implies
$$
z_0-\overline{z_0}=0
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
z_0+\overline{z_0}+i=0
$$
The first case gives $z_0=\overline{z_0}$, but this is impossible, because it would entail $z_0$ is real but then $z_0^2+2=-iz_0$ is a contradiction: the left-hand side is real, the right-hand side is purely imaginary.

The second case gives, by conjugation, also
$$
\overline{z_0}+z_0-i=0
$$
and so $i=-i$, which is again a contradiction.

Note that an equation with complex coefficient *can* have both $z_0$ and $\overline{z_0}$ as roots, provided this is not required for *all* roots: consider
$$
(z-i)(z+i)(z-2i)=0
$$
that has roots $i$, $-i$ and $2i$, where the first two roots are conjugate of each other.

---

If *all* complex (and non real) roots come in pair, that is, *for all roots $z_0$ also $\overline{z_0}$ is a root*, then the equation has real coefficients, as soon as one of them is real.